# htaccess redirecting http to https creates redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect my website from http to https using .htaccess file. The error I am getting is: website.com redirected you too many times.

Here is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

The above works fine and does what it needs to do. The problem comes from the following:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have put "website.com" instead of my own domain in the example above.

Comment: Why are you redirecting to the HTTP version in the last one? Where did you place those last two rules, in relation to the rest? Stuff like this should always come first, before you do other internal rewrites.

Comment: I have changed it to https on that line. Also i have placed the last two sections before and after the internal rewrites but get same error

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to redirect to www and https, and it is working. it should be placed first in the .htaccess file. Errors with redirections can take some time to correct, redirections is cached for some time.

```txt
# BEGIN Custom redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# END Custom redirect
```

You might want something like this:

```txt
# BEGIN Custom redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# END Custom redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

this fixed my problem